# Global function repository

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have several `Control` such as `ToolStripMenuItem` and `Button` that need to have a function bound to their click event. They will either generate a new `Form` or add a `TabPage` to a current `TabControl`. I may end up having several different `Control` that will need the same function, so I thought of making a Global function repository.

I would have a class named `Services` looking like this:

```
public class Services {
    TabControl container;
    delegate void fonction(int id);
    Dictionary<string, fonction> functions = new Dictionary<string, fonction>();

    public Services(TabControl control) {
        container = control;
        InitFunctions();
    }

    public Delegate Getfunction(string name) {
        if (functions.ContainsKey(name))
            return functions[name];
        else 
            throw new NotImplementedException("Failed to instantiate " + name );
    }

    // List of all the desired functions
    // Function example
    private void ProductLoan(int id) {
        string name = "Loan"+id.ToString();
        Form newForm = new Loan();
        newForm.Text = Properties.Resources.MakeLoan;
        newForm.ShowDialog();
    }
    private void InitFunctions() {
        fonction f = new fonction(ProductLoan);
        functions.Add("Loan", f);
        // For each functions
        // f = new fonction(name);
        // functions.Add(name, f);
    }
}
```

This class would be instantiated when the program start and stored globally so it can be accessed everywhere. **Correct me if I am wrong to proceed like this, but I didn't make the `Services` class static since it needs to have an instance of the `TabControl` and to initialise the function list.**

I have no clue if this is a good idea so I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: You could make static assign `TabControl` once, at the load. I prefer static members to do "generic things"

Comment: Interesting, but I would still need to initialise the function list. The `Services` class could be satic though, since no parameters are required. My only concern is that any programmer could try to get a function even if he didn't assign the TabControl. I wanna make sure the only way to use `Services` is when it has the TabControl instance/reference AND the function list initialised.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What programming environment are you using? I know that in Visual Studio, if you have several controls using the same method you can make the method under one of the click events and then, for each control that requires the same method, you can bind that method by having the controls actually bind to the click event of the first control you added that method to. As far as creating a repository that contains each function necessary, I have always had better luck just making the individual click events, I would suggest just making a class to hold the functions and making it static. Because Services needs something else instantiated first, just instantiate the TabControl then the static class holding your methods.

Comment: It is indeed Visual Studio that I use. The first control to get the click event binded is the `ToolStripMenu`. How I could use it's functions in other controls generated dynamicaly is yet a mystery to me. I would probably need to pass my menu all over the program.

Comment: You wouldn't _have_ to pass it all over the place _depending_ on what the method is supposed to do. What you can do is, in the graphical editor, click on 'control' that is supposed to use the same method as the first 'control' you coded. Then under the events menu on the side, click the 'OnClick' method and there should be a drop-down that will allow you to choose the original click method for whatever 'control' you programmed first

Comment: The thing is that both my menu and my controls are generated dynamically, so I don't know what functions the menu will hold or even where it will be until the program is executed.

Comment: Ok then, I'm sorry I was not able to help. Good luck with your program. What will be determining what is generated?

Comment: I ended up making my class Static. As for wat will be determining the content generation, the user rights will determine what the user can and cannot do, then append to a root menu node the ToolStripMenuItems with the proper function binded to it. Then the same process is used inside the forms generated by these events.

Answer (score 1):

You could create something like `TabController` and `PopupController` with public instance methods for creating tabs and forms respectively. The `TabController` will probably have a dependency on `TabControl` and the `PopupContorller` will have a dependency on parent form (if needed). Every `Control` will have it's own event handler where the method from `TabController` and `PopupController` will be called.

**UPD:**

Since the `Controls` are created dynamically, a common facility for wiring the event handlers may be a good idea. But the wiring logic should be separated from event handler implementation logic to make it more readable and maintainable. For example `IntelligentEventHandlerWiringManager` could have a dependencies for `TabController` and `PopupController`.

Comment: I was hoping for a class that would provide me both services for the TabControl and new Forms. So I would end up having `Services` with two controllers.

Comment: The main idea is that you don't need a dictionary with delegates if could just call the instance methods directly. As for separation of TabController and PopupController - they seem to have different responsibilities. Two natural dependencies look better for me than single one, composite and completely unnatural.